# Symfony 4 voters - OnetoMany relation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an Application entity that stores an Advert id with an user id

```
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Application", mappedBy="author", orphanRemoval=true)
 */
 private $applications;
 }
```

Application Entity

```
class Application
{

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Advert", inversedBy="applications")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $advert;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="applications")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $author;
}
```

What i want is a voter that can deny an action if current user already applied for a specific ad ( when viewing the ad )
So far 
In voter tryied

class AdvertApplicationsVoter extends Voter
{

```
protected function supports($attribute, $subject)
{
    return in_array($attribute, ['APP_APPLY', 'ADVERT_APPLY'])  && $subject instanceof Application;
}

/**
 * @param string $attribute
 * @param mixed $subject
 * @param TokenInterface $token
 * @return bool
 */
protected function voteOnAttribute($attribute, $subject, TokenInterface $token)
{
    $user = $token->getUser();
    $apl = $user->getApplications();
    // if the user is anonymous, do not grant access
    if (!$user instanceof User) {
        return false;
    }

    switch ($attribute) {
        case 'APP_APPLY':
            return $this->dw($user, $subject);
            break;
        case 'ADVERT_APPLY':
            // logic to determine if the user can VIEW
            // return true or false
            break;
    }

    return false;
}

private function applied(?User $user, Advert $app)
{
    return $user->getId() === $app->getApplications()->getKeys();
}
private function aa(?User $user, Application $app)
{
    return $user->getApplications() === $app->getAdvert();
}

private function dw(?User $user, Application $app)
{
    foreach($user->getApplications() as $app) {
        if ($app->getAdvert() === $app) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
 }
}
```

I'm getting access abstained, i don't know how to debug a voter

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you have updated the `support` method from voter ? 

[ Your job is to determine if your voter should vote on the attribute/subject combination. If you return true, voteOnAttribute() will be called. Otherwise, your voter is done: some other voter should process this.](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html#creating-the-custom-voter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you properly set up your voter (so with the **supports** and **voteOnAttribute** method).

Then you just have to change your method :

```
private function dw(?User $user, Advert $advert)
{
    foreach($user->getApplications() as $userApplication) {
        if ($userApplication->getAdvert() === $advert) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
 }
}
```

The problem with your method is that you are comparing an **ArrayCollection** with an **application object**.

Comment: Well I just realized that we are using Application instead of Advert, you have to change the subject to Advert instead of Application and keep the code inside the function which compare every advert from the user to the one you want to compare